# Powershell: Creating Custom DataGridView

Tags: arrays, powershell, datagridview

So I'm trying to create a custom Datagridview to put into a GUI program I've made but I'm having some trouble.

So far I have this:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)

$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 4
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Process"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "ID"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "Description"
$dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Memory"

$row1 = get-process -property name | select Name

$rows = @($row1)
foreach ($row in $rows)
{    
$dataGridView.Rows.Add($row.name)}
$form.ShowDialog()
```

My question is this:

How do I go about assigning different columns to differnt properties, so column 'process' would be for the procress name, column 'id' would be for the process id and so on.

so far, all I've managed to do is to assign one column a input range: Process Name.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loop on all processes, and add each process properties in the order you have defined the columns:

```
get-process | foreach{
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add($_.Name,$_.ID,$_.Description,$_.WorkingSet)
}
```

You could also generate the columns dynamically by selecting the properties you want to display, each property becomes a column name, and use the grid's DataSource property and an Array list to add the objects to the grid:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)

$gps = get-process | select Name,ID,Description,@{n='Memory';e={$_.WorkingSet}}
$list = New-Object System.collections.ArrayList
$list.AddRange($gps)

$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView -Property @{
    Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
    ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
    DataSource = $list
}

$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks Shay. Just a quick question, how do you go about settings the size of the column(width). $dataGridView.Columns[1].size = 430?

Answer (score 2):

But why no to user `Out-GridView` from PoSH?:

`get-process | select name, process, id, description, workingSet | Out-GridView`

Answer (score 1):

Akim - scripters try one-liners with output you can see but do little with, while programmers think about a user interface and putting control of the output in the user's hands, thus System.Windows.Forms.Form is a powershell programmer's best friend.

Shay - I have been doing some programming to use a DataGridView and my experience so far shows me I must take control of defining the DataGridView properties and NOT use .DataSource as shown in one example above. Convenient as it is, you do not then do much with your DataGridView other than show it on the form.

I started by setting .ColCount to the number of columns I wanted. Then named the columns. Thereafter I can tweak each column's properties by numbered location or name. I chose to let the user SORT on selected columns. As of 2013-03-23 I am still working on how to set the backgroundcolor of cells that I want to highlight. Should have that answer soon for those wanting to do the same. One example I found uses the value in the cell, not the location.

```
$datagridview = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$datagridview.ColumnCount = 8
$datagridview.Columns[0].Name = "#ID"
$datagridview.Columns[1].Name = "Name"
...[snip]...
$datagridview.Columns[7].Name = "Company"
$datagridview.Columns["Name"].SortMode = "Automatic"
$datagridview.Columns[8].SortMode = "Automatic"
$datagridview.Columns[0].Width = 50
$datagridview.Columns["Description"].Width = 350
...[snip]...
foreach ($_ in $arraylist){[void]$datagridview.Rows.Add($($_.ID), $($_.Name),$($_.Path), $($_.Description), $($_.VM), $($_.WS), $($_.CPU), $($_.Company))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways to fiddle with cell backgroundcolors and only had success with Add_CellPainting. Heed the MSDN warning to NOT set the cellstyle in a specific location unless you truly want that location changed no matter what the user does. In the code below, row 2 column 4 is red no matter how you sort the datagridview. That could be an OOPS or did you really want that. Hmmm.... setting by value does all matching values, so if you have non-unique values then maybe you need additional logic to change only the one you want and repaint if the contents change.

```
$datagridview.Add_CellPainting(
{
param($Null, $EventArgs)
if ($([String]$EventArgs.Value).ToLower().Contains("ms") -eq $True) { $EventArgs.CellStyle.BackColor = "Blue" ; $EventArgs.CellStyle.ForeColor = "White" }
if ($([String]$EventArgs.Value).ToLower().Contains("windows") -eq $True) { $EventArgs.CellStyle.BackColor = "Yellow" }
if ($([String]$EventArgs.Value).ToLower().Contains("windows powershell") -eq $True) { $EventArgs.CellStyle.BackColor = "Green" }
if (($EventArgs.RowIndex -eq 2) -and ($EventArgs.ColumnIndex -eq 4)) {$EventArgs.CellStyle.BackColor = "Red" }
}
) # End of Add_CellPainting
```

Answer (score 0):

Have since found another way to highlight the cell of my choosing:

```
$Script:PS_Log_Viewer_Form_row = $PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.Rows.Add("$($PS_Log_Viewer_total_records_ctr)", "$($PS_Log_Viewer_Form_line_date_time_sub)","$($PS_Log_Viewer_Form_line_acct)","$($PS_Log_Viewer_Form_line_msg)", "$($PS_Log_Viewer_Form_full_filename)-$($PS_Log_Viewer_file_records)")

$PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.Rows[$PS_Log_Viewer_Form_row].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = "BlanchedAlmond"
```

And searching all rows and setting (think find all):

```
for ($i = ($PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex - 1) ; $i -gt 0 ; $i-- )
{
if ($PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.Rows[$i].Cells[3].Value.Contains("$($find_form_middle_flp_textbox_1.Text)") )
{
$PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.Rows[$i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = $find_form_middle_flp_color_combobox_dropdownlist.SelectedItem
$PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = $i
$find_form_bottom_remarks = "Previous found at $($i)."
$i = 0
} # End of if ($PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.Rows[$i].Cells[3].Value.Contains("$($Script:PS_Log_Viewer_search_string)") )
} # End of for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $PS_Log_Viewer_Form_dataGridView1.RowCount ; $i++ )
```