# Exceptions not being added in datagridview for the ping failed servers

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I am trying to add even the ping failed servers in the report but exception is not adding the results to datagridview.. where am I going wrong?

```
function Test-Ping {
  $Servers = Get-Content $textboxServerName.txt
  $Set = @()
  foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    try {
      $Set += Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 |
              Select -Property @{n='ServerName';e={$_.PSComputerName}},
                               @{n='IPv4';e={$_.IPV4Address}},
                               @{n='IPv6';e={$_.IPV6Address}},
                               @{n='ProtocolAddress';e={$_.ProtocolAddress}} -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch [System.Exception] {
      $Set += @{n='ServerName';e={$_.PSComputerName}},
              @{n='IPv4';e={N/A}},
              @{n='IPv6';e={N/A}},
              @{n='ProtocolAddress';e={N/A}}
    }
    $table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $Set -FilterWMIProperties
    Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $table
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

- `Get-Content $textboxServerName.txt` may not work the way you think. Do you want to append the suffix `.txt` to the value of `$textboxServerName`? If the variable (a string?) doesn't have that property, the expression will evaluate to `$null`, so `Get-Content` will fail with a `ParameterBindingValidation` exception. Use double quotes to prevent that:

  ```
  $Servers = Get-Content "$textboxServerName.txt"
  ```

  Or is `$textboxServerName` a `TextBox` element and you want the text value of that element? In that case you misspelled the property name (`Text`).

  ```
  $Servers = Get-Content $textboxServerName.Text
  ```
- In the `catch` block the [current object variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$_` holds the exception object, not the result of `Test-Connection` (which had failed anyway, and thus didn't produce a result in the first place). Use the variable `$Server` instead.
- Appending a list of hashtables to `$Set` doesn't work the same way as a list of [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) in a `Select-Object` statement. You need to create a custom object there.

  ```
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'ServerName'      = $Server
    'IPv4'            = 'N/A'
    'IPv6'            = 'N/A'
    'ProtocolAddress' = 'N/A'
  }
  ```
- Appending to an array in a loop is bound to perform poorly. It's usually better to just output the objects inside the loop, collect the entire loop output in a variable, and load it into the grid view after the loop finished:

  ```
  $Set = foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    ...
  }
  $table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $Set -FilterWMIProperties
  Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $table
  ```
- If you want to append to the grid view with every iteration of the loop you should probably just [add new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468613/1630171) to it:

  ```
  foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    try {
      $o = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop |
           Select -Property @{n='ServerName';e={$_.PSComputerName}},
                            @{n='IPv4';e={$_.IPV4Address}},
                            @{n='IPv6';e={$_.IPV6Address}},
                            @{n='ProtocolAddress';e={$_.ProtocolAddress}}
    } catch [System.Exception] {
      $o = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
             'ServerName'      = $Server
             'IPv4'            = 'N/A'
             'IPv6'            = 'N/A'
             'ProtocolAddress' = 'N/A'
           }
    }
    $datagridview1.Rows.Add($o.ServerName, $o.IPv4, $o.IPv6, $o.ProtocolAddress)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar for all your help on this.. I have built the function based on given suggestion and got below error..

Comment: ERROR: Exception calling "Add" with "9" argument(s): "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

Comment: [google://Rows+cannot+be+programmatically+added+to+the+DataGridView's+rows+collection+when+the+control+is+data-bound](http://www.google.com/search?q=Rows+cannot+be+programmatically+added+to+the+DataGridView's+rows+collection+when+the+control+is+data-bound)

Comment: I have tried couple of solutions given in the google results but unable to fix the errors.. would you please help in this ?

Comment: If you can't change your gridview behavior you can always go back to appending to an array inside the loop. Just fix the object creation in the `catch` block (see third bullet point).